# replay decrypted ssl traffic with tcpreplay

Tags: ssl, https, wireshark, pcap, tcpreplay

I have an pcap format from some https traffic from one of my web-servers.
So I can use the key from my webserver to decrypt the traffic in wireshark. The problem I'm now facing is that I can't get an unencrypted pcap file from wireshark.

I want to use the pcap file unencrypted on tcpreplay to replay the trace for monitoring purposes. How do I create a pcap file with the decrypted https traffic from my other pcap file?